# Swing awt component method getName from setName?

Tags: java, swing

Trying to add a `getName()` method to a `setName()` based on this method `void java.awt.Component.setName(String arg0)` but without luck. The button below is loaded into the contentPane.

I need to add an actionlistener to a button instantiated in this method (either based on setName or something else similar):

```
public JButton JButtonComponent(String btnRef) {
    
    button = new JButton("Convert to binary");
    button.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width/4,unitHeight));
    
    button.addActionListener(this);
    button.setName("Binary"); // my set name 
    
    return button;
}
```

This is my actionPerformed method:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    System.out.println(e.getSource());

}
```

And the above system print outputs:

```
javax.swing.JButton[Binary,270,14,90x33,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=Convert,defaultCapable=true]
```

My question is how do i get the name value i've defined in JButtonComponent from the ActionEvent? - The setName value is clearly in the ActionEvent e but no method seems to be right for the object to extract the value so i can do a compare.
And is this the best method to define an "id" like you would in HTML if you were to compare?

Comment: 1) `JButton` inherits `getName()` from `Component`. 2) See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Your `JButton` definition code should be:

```
button.setText("Binary");
```

Your `ActionListener` code should be:

```
JButton button = (JButton) event.getSource();
String text = button.getText();
```

You can also use the `JButton` ActionCommand `String` to pass along additional; information.

Answer (score 0):

> either based on setName or something else similar

Don't use getName/setName for something like this.

There is already an API that allows you to use an "action command".

For a `JButton` you can use:

```
button.setActionCommand("Binary");
```

Then in the `ActionListener` you use:

```
String command = e.getActionCommand();
```

> The setName value is clearly in the ActionEvent

No it isn't. A reference to the source object is contained in the ActionEvent. You need to first access the source before you can access the methods of the source object:

```
JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
System.out.println( button.getName() );
```